# Deadlock in vertica db for concurrent access of same table different rows

Tags: database, deadlock, vertica

I have a table in Vertica database that looks like this:

[image]

There are four processes p1, p2, p3, p4 that run concurrently and perform operations on their respecive rows, i.e.

p1 --->  Select last value, Update start time, Update end time on p1 row.

p2 --->  Select last value, Update start time, Update end time on p2 row.

p3 --->  Select last value, Update start time, Update end time on p3 row.

p4 --->  Select last value, Update start time, Update end time on p4 row.

All the four processes access only and only its own specific row, e.g. p1 never access row of p2.

Yet, I am facing deadlock issue as p1 running a select query on p1's row and holding a lock, at the same time p4 tries to update p4's row.

Transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED.

What can I do to avoid this deadlock?

### Edit 1:

Here are sample queries that the processes execute:

```
UPDATE $log_table SET start_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(1) WHERE process_name = '$taskname'

SELECT last_value FROM $log_table WHERE process_name ='$taskname'

UPDATE $log_table SET end_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(1) WHERE process_name = '$taskname'
```

### Edit 2:

Sample perl script

```
$taskname = "p1"   # respective process names. for process1 its p1. for process2 its p2 and so on. #
$log_table = "config table name"

# Update start time 
$current_timestamp = localtime();
$sqlstmt = "UPDATE $log_table SET start_time = '$current_timestamp' WHERE process_name = '$taskname'";
$db->prepare("$sqlstmt") or handle_error();
$handle->execute() or handle_error();

# do other stuff 

# Fetch last modified value
$sqlstmt = "SELECT last_value FROM $log_table WHERE process_name ='$taskname'";
$db->prepare("$sqlstmt") or handle_error();
$handle->execute() or handle_error();
$result = $handle->fetchrow();
# do other stuff


# Update end time
$current_timestamp = localtime();
$sqlstmt = "UPDATE $log_table SET end_time = '$current_timestamp' WHERE process_name = '$taskname'";
$db->prepare("$sqlstmt") or handle_error();
$handle->execute() or handle_error();
$result = $handle->fetchrow();
```

Comment: Hmmm... can you please share the SQL of your transaction? BTW... P1 is supposed to release its lock when it COMMITs the transaction so that P4 can continue ...

Comment: The queries don't run as you wrote them.  `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` would work, but `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(1)` would not. And how many rows do you expect from `SELECT last_value FROM $log_table WHERE process_name='$task_name'` ? Can you supply or make up sample data to illustrate?

Comment: @marcothesane sorry my bad. I gave some example of queries.

1. Please check my latest edit, I have added a perl script. Actually, I am firing queries from the perl script. The four copies of same perl scripts are the p1, p2 p3 and p4. I am not fetching the current_timestamp from query but from the perl script, so current_timestamp is not a concern here.

2. There will be only four rows. As I have given in the question, the same kind of data would be there.

Comment: Thanks for that, so far. What do you do with the `$result` variable ? I mean: `SELECT last_value FROM $log_table WHERE process_name ='$taskname'` will return a cursor with as many single-column rows as there are rows in `$log_table`. But you run just one `fetchrow()` with no control which will be the first `last_value` you get. I'm creating a table with: `process_name CHAR(2), start_time INT, end_time INT, last_value INT`, and try to trigger the deadlock myself. Is the table you're working with different?

Comment: @marcothesane Yes that's correct. Thats what it should be. I just need the first of last_value column. The select query is intended to return only one value as there would be only one row per process. I do some calculation on the $result value afterwards but that's not important here.

I am using the same table that I have given in the question, same as your table schema also.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that Vertica does not actually update an existing row, but it marks an existing row as deleted, by adding a new delete vector in the physical storage, and inserts a new row. This also involves an exclusive lock on the table. Are your connections AUTOCOMMIT? If not, try changing to AUTOCOMMIT, and see what happens. If that does not help, there's some design possibilities ...

I created the table, and four scripts like this:

```
SET SESSION AUTOCOMMIT TO OFF;
UPDATE log_table SET start_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE process_name = 'p1';
SELECT last_val FROM log_table WHERE process_name ='p1';
UPDATE log_table SET end_time   = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE process_name = 'p1';
COMMIT;
```

Then, I used a query driver to run the four scripts in parallel. Waiting for two seconds between the execution of each statement in the script. I also alternated by adding or removing `BEGIN WORK` / `COMMIT WORK` statements. I could not trigger a deadlock, I'm afraid, so I'm flying blind here.

One less invasive alternative: different ROS containers per process name:

`ALTER TABLE log_table PARTITION BY process_name REORGANIZE;`

You could be lucky to diminish deadlocks - although a delete (and an update is a delete, then insert) always issues an exclusive table lock - but they could deadlock each other a bit less.

The brute force way would be:

```
CREATE TABLE log_p1 (last_val INT start_time TIMESTAMP,end_time TIMESTAMP);
CREATE TABLE log_p2 (last_val INT start_time TIMESTAMP,end_time TIMESTAMP);
CREATE TABLE log_p3 (last_val INT start_time TIMESTAMP,end_time TIMESTAMP);
CREATE TABLE log_p4 (last_val INT start_time TIMESTAMP,end_time TIMESTAMP);
CREATE VIEW log_table AS -- just for reporting, not for maintenance
          SELECT 'p1' AS proc_name, * FROM log_p1
UNION ALL SELECT 'p2' AS proc_name, * FROM log_p2
UNION ALL SELECT 'p3' AS proc_name, * FROM log_p3
UNION ALL SELECT 'p4' AS proc_name, * FROM log_p4
;
```

And the four scripts would only differ in `p4` versus `p1`:

```
SELECT * FROM p1; -- fetch single row output into your application
TRUNCATE TABLE p1;
-- bind "last_val" and "end_time" host variables
INSERT INTO p1 VALUES(? , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?);
SELECT last_val FROM log_p1;
TRUNCATE TABLE p1;
-- bind "last_val" and "start_time" host variables
INSERT INTO p1 VALUES(? , ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
COMMIT;
```